# How can I change # by code using interpolation

Tags: angular

How can I change #card10 and "VerBoton10" by values ​​of the object?

I can do it in the div texts but not in the places I indicate.

What I want to achieve is to use the names obtained by interpolation in both the HTML and TypeScript codes to avoid having one line per element.

Thank you for your attention.

You can see the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skast9

```html
  <div *ngFor="let card of cards"
    [style.background]="'grey'"
    [style.border]="'1px solid red'"
  >
    <div class="card">
      <div #card10 class="overlay">
        <div>Name: {{ card.name }}</div>
        <br />
        <div>ID: {{ card.id}}</div>
        <br />
        <button  *ngIf="verBoton10"
             (click)="onClickHecho( card.id )"
        >
          Hecho {{ card.name }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button (click)="reponer()" >
          Reponer botones
        </button>
```

```js
import { Component,
  Renderer2,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef, } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  cards = [
    {name: '#card10', id: 10, boton: 'verBoton10'},
    {name: '#card11', id: 11, boton: 'verBoton11'},
    {name: '#card12', id: 12, boton: 'verBoton12'},
    {name: '#card13', id: 13, boton: 'verBoton13'},
    {name: '#card14', id: 14, boton: 'verBoton14'}
];

@ViewChild('card10', { static: false }) card7: ElementRef;

  verBoton10 = true;
  verBoton11 = true;
  verBoton12 = true;
  verBoton13 = true;
  verBoton14 = true;


constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2) {
    }

onClickHecho(numCard: number) {
    console.log(numCard);
    switch (numCard) {
      case 10:
       this.verBoton10 = false;
       this.renderer.setStyle( this.card7.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'green' );
       break;
      case 11:
       this.verBoton11 = false;
       break;
      case 12:
       this.verBoton12 = false;
       break;
      case 13:
       this.verBoton13 = false;
       break;
      case 14:
       this.verBoton14 = false;
       break;
    }
  }

  reponer(){
    this.verBoton10 = true;
     this.renderer.setStyle( this.card7.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'grey' );
    this.verBoton11 = true;
    this.verBoton12 = true;
    this.verBoton13 = true;
    this.verBoton14 = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: `onClickHecho(item)` and then you have the entire object.

Comment: Why you do not simply use item instead of cards[indice] ?

Comment: What’s the purpose of #card10 and verBoton10 ? Could you explain what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kept the last answer for historical purposes.

Now what you want is to make the card green and the button inside disappear when you click on it. Here the updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xt5gx

There's multiple way to achieve this requirement. If the activation data is needed in the server you have to put it in the model, it'll be like `{name: string, id: number, activated: boolean}`. But if this data is not needed at the backend you can keep it only in the front (the suggested solution).

```html
  <div *ngFor="let card of cards; let idx=index"
    [style.background]="'grey'"
    [style.border]="'1px solid red'"
  >
    <div class="card">
      <div [ngStyle]="!activeCards[idx] ? {'background-color':'green'} : {'background-color':'grey'}" class="overlay">
        <div>Name: {{ card.name }}</div>
        <br />
        <div>ID: {{ card.id}}</div>
        <br />
        <button  *ngIf="activeCards[idx]" (click)="onClickHecho(idx)">
          Hecho {{ card.name }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button (click)="reponer()" >
    Reponer botones
  </button>
```

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  cards = [];
  activeCards = [];

  constructor() {
    this.cards = [
      {name: '#card10', id: 10},
      {name: '#card11', id: 11},
      {name: '#card12', id: 12},
      {name: '#card13', id: 13},
      {name: '#card14', id: 14}
    ];
    this.activateAll();
  }

  onClickHecho(idex: number) {
    this.activeCards[idex] = false;
  }

  reponer(){
    this.activateAll();
  }

  activateAll() {
    this.activeCards = this.cards.map(() => true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is perfectly my doubt raised, however to ask the question I simplify the issue by leaving it only in two possible states of the card, however in reality I need the card to take multiple states and that these state can keep them in a base of data.
Is it better to open another question?
Thank you

Comment: Yes and this time put your complet code, i do not undurstand the problem

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want to control the activation of the buttons by clicking on card number 10. In the other side, you can control the card 10 appearance only in the html part.

Check this code and tell me :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tluc9y?file=src/app/app.component.html

```html
  <div *ngFor="let card of cards"
    [style.background]="'grey'"
    [style.border]="'1px solid red'"
  >
    <div class="card">
      <div [ngStyle]="!activateButtons && card.id === 10 ? {'background-color':'green'} : {'background-color':'grey'}" class="overlay">
        <div>Name: {{ card.name }}</div>
        <br />
        <div>ID: {{ card.id}}</div>
        <br />
        <button  *ngIf="activateButtons" (click)="onClickHecho(card.id)">
          Hecho {{ card.name }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button (click)="reponer()" >
    Reponer botones
  </button>
```

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  cards = [
    {name: '#card10', id: 10},
    {name: '#card11', id: 11},
    {name: '#card12', id: 12},
    {name: '#card13', id: 13},
    {name: '#card14', id: 14}
];

activateButtons = true;

onClickHecho(numCard: number) {
    if (numCard === 10 ) {
      this.activateButtons = false;
    }
  }

  reponer(){
    this.activateButtons = true;
  }
}
```

You can extract `!activateButtons && card.id === 10` in another variable like `isGreenCard` for more readability.

Comment: Thanks, Elma.
I'm sorry but my English is very bad.
What I really need is to be able to make a substitution of the different buttons (10,11,12,13,14 ....) in order to avoid having a lot of repertoire code with the only change of which button is applied, in your example the changes are applied to all the buttons, what I need is that they only apply to the one that corresponds to the index that is passed as an argument.
Thank you

Comment: How many buttons you have ? Imagine that you have 20 or more ! Do you think is a good idea to declare a variable for each button ?

Comment: I have 8 cards with a button in each of them, that I need to hide when pressed and also change the css in two components siblings, so the code to perform behind the button is long and repetitive, that's why I'm looking for a way to have only one cycle for creating the elements in the HTML and then using interpolation that allows me to control all the buttons with a single code that takes the number of the button as an argument.
.

Comment: ............................
 <div # card10 class = "overlay">
        <div> Name: {{card.name}} </ div>
        <br />
        <div> ID: {{card.id}} </ div>
        <br />
        <button * ngIf = "verBoton10"
...................................

The problem is that I do not know how to do that instead of:
 <div # card10 class = "overlay">
I can do something like
 <div "#" + {{card.id}} class = "overlay">

and instead of * ngIf = "verBoton10" something like
* ngIf = "verBoton" + {{card.id}}

Comment: So, what you want is when you click on a button the card becomes green and the button disapear. The other buttons stay enchaged. Am i correct ?