# Use of interpolation in HTML to reduce code

Tags: angular

In my previous question 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692694/how-can-i-change-by-code-using-interpolation)
and thanks to the answer of @Elma Cherb I learned how to use ngStyle to solve my problem.

I need to expand the question to be able to change my code in a way that allows me to use interpolation to change # card10 for a combination with the index such as "#card" + index.
Or use the previous solution but with multiple parameters not only with two.

```html
 <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards; let indice=index"
    [style.background]="'#F2F2F2'"
    [style.border]="'1px solid black'"
  >
    <div class="card">
      <div #card10 class="overlay">
        <h4>CONTROL  </h4>
        <div>{{card.name}}</div>
        <br />
        <div>{{card.id}}</div>
        <br />
        <button
          *ngIf="verBoton10"
          class="btn-material"
          (click)="onClickHecho(card.id)"
        >
          Hecho
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
```

I have put my complete code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/kamishibai

Comment: What's the concrete problem you're trying to solve? (unrelated: why are you using dynamic style binding to set completely static styles? Why not just use `style="background: #F2F2F2; border: 1px solid black"`, or better, a CSS class?)

Comment: This is my first application in Angular and it may be full of errors.
I would appreciate it if you could correct what you see wrong in my code by changing it and publishing the solution.


What I intend to do is avoid having so much HTML code in row-cards-component.html, instead of having a <div> for each card: card7, card8, card9, card10, have a unique one using ngFor to create them dynamically, the problem is like knowing in which card I have to perform the actions of the onClickHecho () function if I do not have defined the `@ViewChild (card7), @ViewChild (card8), ..........`

Comment: You already had an answer. Have you read it?

Comment: Yes, I've read it and it seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use interpolation for it.

You should use the same name - `#card` for all of them, and then get those elements in the ts file by using [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

I forked your stackblitz and edited it to work [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kamishibai-awqp9p).

The code should look like.

```js
@ViewChildren('card') eleCards: QueryList<ElementRef>;

onClickHecho(index: number) {
  if ( this.horaControl10 < 10 ) {
    this.mensajeControlAntesHora();
  } else {
    this.hechoService.hecho10.emit(true);
    this.verBoton10 = false;
    const card = this.eleCards.toArray()[index];
    if (this.horaControl10 >= 20) {
      this.hechoService.hecho10.emit(false);
      this.mensajeControlDespuesHora();
      this.renderer.setStyle(card.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'orange' );
    } else {
      this.hechoService.hecho10.emit(true);
      this.renderer.setStyle(card.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'green' );
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards; let indice=index"
  [style.background]="'#F2F2F2'"
  [style.border]="'1px solid black'"
>
<div class="card">
    <div #card class="overlay">
      <h4>CONTROL</h4>
      <div># Verificar que no existen cristales en la zona.</div>
      <br />
      <div># Otra tarea.</div>
      <br />
      <button
        *ngIf="verBoton9"
        class="btn-material"
        (click)="onClickHecho(indice)"
      >
        Hecho
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code has totally solved my problem.